# How to access UI elements of a custom user control in Expression Blend

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, custom-controls

I am new to Expression Blend. I want to create a custom user control which consists of an image control. I want to be able to set different image source for each instance of the custom control. I am able to do this in code-behind, but I couldn't find a way to do this directly inside Expression Blend (like what can be done to the image control in property panel). The image control inside the custom control is not accessible in the visual tree. If I change the image source in the custom control xaml, it applies to all instances.

For example in this window visual tree, the custom user control appears only as one item, I couldn't access the image control inside it.

[image: Project Visual Tree]

So I want to know is it possible to configure UI elements of a custom user control inside Expression Blend? If so, how?

The reason I am asking is because I am working on Silverlight for Embedded. So the xaml and code-behind are in different projects. Whether it is possible to do this will have an impact on where I put the image resources.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {

        public ImageSource MyImage
        {
            get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(MyImageProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MyImageProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty MyImageProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("MyImage", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(UserControl1));


        public UserControl1()
        {

            InitializeComponent();            
        }
    }
```

On the XAML

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             xmlns:me="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Image Source="{Binding MyImage, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
            Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type me:UserControl1}}}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Now your User control has MyImage property. Set image to this property from Expression Blend

On the silverlight

```
<Grid>
            <Image Source="{Binding MyImage}" name="MYIMG" />
        </Grid>
```

in code behind

```
public UserControl1()
            {

                InitializeComponent();   
                MYIMG.DataContext = this;// THIS IS IMPORTANT;         
            }
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried but doesn't help. As part of a custom user control, I am able to see the image control and I am able to set its source in code-behind. But my intention is to see if it is possible to set image source **inside** Expression Blend for each instance of custom control, not code-behind.

Comment: Ok I see. The idea is to use dependency property and bind to this property in xaml. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, sorry to say that I tried and though it works in WPF application, it doesn't work in Silverlight. AncestorType is not supported in the Silverlight version that I am using (I am working on Silverlight for Windows Embedded so the Silverlight version is 3). I tried setting RelativeSource to TemplatedParent. It can compile and run, but doesn't show any image. :(

Comment: Thank you so much! It is working on both WPF and Silverlight now. But when I move to Silverlight for Windows Embedded, there is still problem. I think it is because of the same problem here:[link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d398d44e-b6b9-4e58-bb1a-89a00051cc6c/add-own-dependencyproperty-to-an-usercontrol). So I am trying to register the dependency property in C++ code-behind but so far still unsuccessful with E_INVALIDARG error. I suspect I did something wrong when registering ImageSource type in SWE. I am still debugging. But for the original topic it can be closed now.